# How to explode a pandas dataframe that has nulls in some rows, but populated in others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have many dataframes coming in that need to be exploded. they look something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, [11,22], [111,222]],
                   'B': [2, [33,44], float('nan')],
                   'C': [3, [55,66], [333,444]],
                   'D': [4, [77,88], float('nan')]
                  })
```

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| A         | B       | C         | D       |
+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| 1         | 2       | 3         | 4       |
+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| [11,22]   | [33,44] | [55,66]   | [77,88] |
+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| [111,222] | NaN     | [333,444] | NaN     |
+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Typically if a column couldn't be exploded I'd just remove it from the column list like so:

```
colList = df.columns.values.tolist()
colList.remove("B")
colList.remove("D")
df = df.explode(colList)
```

But that would leave me with a dataframe that looks like:

```
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| A   | B       | C   | D       |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| 1   | 2       | 3   | 4       |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| 11  | [33,44] | 55  | [77,88] |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| 22  | [33,44] | 66  | [77,88] |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| 111 | NaN     | 333 | NaN     |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
| 222 | NaN     | 444 | NaN     |
+-----+---------+-----+---------+
```

I still need to explode those columns (B and D in example), but if I do, it'll throw an error due to the nulls. How can I successfully explode dataframes with this sort of problem?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input (DataFrame constructor), this table is not easy to reproduce by copy/pasting.

Comment: Also, when non NaNs, do all the lists in a given row have the same number of items?

Comment: @mozway sorry, this is now added. Yes when non NaNs, all the lists in a record have the same amount of items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) each column separately and deduplicate the index before [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
def explode_dedup(s):
    s = s.explode()
    return s.set_axis(
        pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([s.index, s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()])
    )


out = pd.concat({c: explode_dedup(df[c]) for c in df}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       A    B    C    D
0 0    1    2    3    4
1 0   11   33   55   77
  1   22   44   66   88
2 0  111  NaN  333  NaN
  1  222  NaN  444  NaN
```

To explode a subset of the columns:

```
cols = ['C', 'D']
others = df.columns.difference(cols)

out = (df[others]
       .join(pd.concat({c: explode_dedup(df[c])
                        for c in cols}, axis=1)
               .droplevel(-1)
            )[df.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
            A         B    C    D
0           1         2    3    4
1    [11, 22]  [33, 44]   55   77
1    [11, 22]  [33, 44]   66   88
2  [111, 222]       NaN  333  NaN
2  [111, 222]       NaN  444  NaN
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, [11,22], [111,222]],
                   'B': [2, [33,44], float('nan')],
                   'C': [3, [55,66], [333,444]],
                   'D': [4, [77,88], float('nan')]
                  })
```

Comment: Wow, your first solution works like a charm. Do we need to deduplicate the index for the concat to work? Also, exploding each column separately makes sense- I'm just not sure how the NaNs are being exploded with the lists- if that makes sense. One NaN vs multiple values in the list.

Comment: Yes the deduplication is important, else the `concat` would fail since `explode` produces duplicated indices. The NaNs are not really exploded but rather created when the Series are concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with null values but with the different indexes of exploded columns. To make it possible to explode all columns at once, we need to replace `NaN`s with some iterables of the same length as any list in its row.

Let's say, we know that any NA is only in a row with lists and each list has only 2 elements. In this case we can map null values with `[None, None]` and then explode the data frame:

```
na_exploded = pd.Series(repeat([None,None], len(df)), index=df.index)
df_exploded = df.mask(df.isna(), na_exploded, axis=0).explode([*df])
```

In general case, we have to take into account some corner cases like null values in scalar rows or columns filled with NA except scalar rows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, [11,22], [111,222,333]],
 'B': [2, None, [33,44,55]],
 'C': [None, [55,66], [333,444,555]],
 'D': [4, None, None]})

is_list = df.map(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any(axis='columns')

na_exploded = (
    df[is_list]
    .apply(lambda x: x.str.len(), axis='columns')
    .max('columns')
    .astype(int)
    .map(lambda x: [None]*x)
)  

df_exploded = df.mask(df.isna(), na_exploded, axis=0).explode([*df])


# Input:
# -----
#                  A             B                C    D
# 0                1             2             None  4.0
# 1         [11, 22]          None         [55, 66]  NaN
# 2  [111, 222, 333]  [33, 44, 55]  [333, 444, 555]  NaN

# Output:
# ------
#      A    B    C    D
# 0    1    2  NaN  4.0
# 1   11  NaN   55  NaN
# 1   22  NaN   66  NaN
# 2  111   33  333  NaN
# 2  222   44  444  NaN
# 2  333   55  555  NaN
```